# nfsroot freezing every once in a while presumably due to network glitch

Tags: linux, nfs, gentoo

**Setup**

I've set up a thin client running gentoo according to [these instructions](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Diskless_nodes). It seems to work quite nicely except that every once in a while it freezes.

I've found that I can duplicate the issue by pulling the network, running ls, and then plugging the network back in. For whatever reason it's not recovering from the loss of network. I would assume that the OS should be able to handle momentary I/O loss (let's say that a hard drive takes a second or two to respond), so I think it can't be just a glitch in the filesystem, but rather that the nfs connection isn't coming back at all. The filesystem is mounted as nfs4 with the following options:

```
rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,namlen=255,hard,proto=udp,port=0,timeo=11,retrans=3,sec=sys,clientaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,local_lock=none,addr=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Previously, I was using no proto spec (defaulting to tcp) and that didn't work any better.

I figure what's happening when I'm not pulling the cord is that the network glitches for a second, something's trying to access a file (seems to be freezing when I'm compiling some software), and then it doesn't recover.

**Question**

What can I do to make the system robust to network problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try options tcp,hard,_netdev. udp protocol is unreliable.

'_netdev ' mount option will prevent crashing of NFS shares.